# AndroidSwipeLayout fixed header

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

Using (for the first time) AndroidSwipeLayout plugin, it seems whole layout has to be "swipeble".

Is there a way to show a fixed header (generic image/text or other view) in the same AndroidSwipeLayout?

P.S.: i use binding port for Xamarin Android, but layout schema is the same

Original Android Component
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Xamarin Android porting
https://components.xamarin.com/view/AndroidSwipeLayout

**UPDATE**
Using  inside a main layout seems to work as expected.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:text="My fixed text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtIncomingCall" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/idSwipeLayout"
        layout="@layout/SwipeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

  <!-- Bottom View Start-->
  <LinearLayout
      android:background="#66ddff00"
      android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:weightSum="1"
      >
    <!--What you want to show-->
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- Bottom View End-->

  <!-- Surface View Start -->
  <LinearLayout
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--What you want to show in SurfaceView-->
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- Surface View End -->

</com.daimajia.swipe.SwipeLayout>
```